# Detect and handle application sudden endtask ,restart and shutdown?

Tags: c#, crash

I have an application that stores an XML Encrypted Document, each time the application wants to access the XML file it have to (decrypt-->read-->write-->encrypt). if a sudden shutdown or restart even a end task from task manager will result on either corrupted data in the XML or a un-encrypted XML file, so in the next run it will produce an error.

What i though about is to store the whole content of the XML in a the database and check if there are any errors then replace the old content.

Any ideas, tips, or thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the decryption/encryption in memory. Never, ever store unencrypted data on disk. Load the encrypted data, decrypt it in memory. When saving, first encrypt in memory, then store.

Replacing the entire content of a file in a way that is safe even in the event of sudden shutdowns is hard. A workaround is to create a new file under a temporary name and when it is written completely to disk, delete the old file and rename the new one. There are other implications of this though, such as security rights specific to the file being lost.

A better, but more advanced option, is to move everything into a database with transaction support.

Comment: +1. The transaction support could include logs which could be used which step of the chain was done or not. Nice idea.

Comment: Can you post a simple example how to store data on memory and read from it, and can you explain about the transaction support.

Comment: @user733659: Check out the MemoryStream class. It behaves like a FileStream, but stores data in memory instead of on disk. In most places where a FileStream is used a MemoryStream can be used instead.